# Extracting character probabilities that were randomly sampled in R

Tags: r, subset, sample

I have the defined the following variables:

```
a <- as.character(1:10)
b <- 100
c <- 10
probs <- c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, rep(0.1/7, 7))
min <- 5
max <- 10
```

I am trying to figure out how to subset the 'probs' argument in the code below to correspond with the characters that are randomly sampled (i.e., randomly sampling characters 5:10)

```
sample(a[min:max], size = round(b/c), replace = TRUE, prob = probs[???])
```

I don't think that probs[min:max] will work as it should, but I am uncertain how to find out for certain if it does. A more complicated scenario is if I want something like

```
a[c(1, 3, 5)]
```

I would then need 'probs' to correspond to characters 1, 3, and 5.

I have tried using probs[get(paste0(...))], but this is not the most direct and efficient way. It doesn't work anyway.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you rescale `probs[min:max]/sum(probs[min:max])` to sum to 1?

Comment: @RuiBarradas While that brings up a point that I neglected to mention, I don't think the probabilities in prob would correspond to the character labels that were randomly sampled...

Comment: Yes, I believe it would. Or at least that's how I read the help page for `sample`: `prob - a vector of probability weights for obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled.` Note also that the probabilities are automatically rescaled to add up to 1 so the code in my comment would be useless.

Comment: Alright thanks! Give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to subset `probs` to be the same subset as `a`, e.g.

```
index = min:max
sample(a[index], size = round(b/c), replace = TRUE, prob = probs[index])
```

For the more complicated scenario, set `index = c(1,3,5)`.

You can see that this works by doing a simulation and comparing the observed probabilities with the true probabilities:

```
set.seed(123)
tmp = sample(a[min:max], size = 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[min:max])
table(tmp)/10000 # the observed probabilities
```

The observed probabilities are roughly all equal, which is consistent with the true probabilities being all equal.

If you take a look at the help files for `sample`, you'll see that `prob` does not need to sum to 1. The function will take care of normalizing the probabilities.